# PHP cookies on Perl

Tags: php, perl, cookies

I'll go straight to the question.

How to read a PHP cookie using Perl? It's seems to be a stupid question, but I just can't make it work.

I'm using a proxy. If cookie exists do this, if not do that. So, regardless of what website I'm requesting, I need to check this cookie.

My PHP script created a cookie called "phpcookie". Now I want to retrieve it's value with Perl with the following script.

```
    use strict; 
    use CGI qw/:standard/; 
    use CGI::Cookie;

    my $cgi = new CGI; 
    my $ck = $cgi->cookie('phpcookie');
```

$ck always returns blank.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: could you show the PHP snippet that created the cookie? If possible, could you also show the corresponding header fields with the cookies in the request from the client to your Perl CGI script (assuming your PHP script is using actual HTTP cookies)?

Comment: I just used setcookie('phpcookie', 'myvalue') on my php script. Firebug showed me that the cookie was successfully created. I'm sorry, I didn't understand your second request.

Comment: can you Show me the Content of the Cookie you set in php?

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect all cookies sent by browser and check for `phpcookie`,

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI qw/:standard/; 

my $cgi = new CGI; 
my @arr = $cgi->cookie();
print Dumper \@arr;
```